# Bluegiga BGScript: How to advertise with event trigger driven?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluegiga

I'm using the BGScript for Bluetooth program. BGScript provides start advertising API. API name is "gap_set_adv_parameters(adv_interval_min, adv_interval_max, adv_channels)(result)"

What I want to do is send an advertising packet when an event happens. Not interval advertising. Is there a way to do it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks,

iBeacon advertising example of BGScript.

https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/29990857-Apple-iBeacon-example

Answer (score 0):

What sort of event are you talking about? If you want to respond to an interrupt from a component in your circuit, you will need to configure `hardware.xml` to make sure the interrupt pin is set properly. Then, depending on the component, you may need to enable interrupts by modifying registers on that component. With all of that configured properly, BGScript will call an event handler method in your script:

```
event hardware_io_port_status(delta, port, irq, state)
```

You can then set advertising parameters at this point. But are you sure you want to set advertising parameters and not just update a Bluetooth characteristic? If you provide a little more info on what you're trying to achieve, I can provide more specific help.